# Do Stack Overflow users need to be so rude?

Tags: discussion, behavior

I have been using Stack Overflow for many years now, and sometimes I ask questions, when I do I try very hard to ask questions in a way that gives the community all they need to be able to answer the question without bogging them down with pointless questions.

But I have noticed a tendency within the community to bully or talk trash to persons who makes even the slightest mistake in the way they ask the question.

Is there anything that can be done to stop this?

Comment: Yes; flag the trash talk or rude comments as such.

Comment: Maybe rethink how awful some of the comments might *not* be, like under your recent question.

Answer (score 4):

If people post rude or offensive comments or answers, just [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) them as such. A ♦ moderator will take action, if appropriate.